# I need to calculate and the display the sum of the total sales in C#

Tags: c#, sql

I want to calculate the SUM of the total sales by Staff Id and I would also like to calculate the total sales for the month in C# but it keeps saying that my Input string is wrong.

here is the code for the total sales by Staff ID

```
 command.CommandText = "SELECT SUM (PriceSold) FROM SALELINE where SALELINE.SoldBy = '" +  comboBox10.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' ";
        string cmd = command.CommandText;
        double result = Convert.ToDouble(cmd);
        textBoxSalesStaffOutput.Text = Convert.ToString(result);
```

here is the code for the sales by month

```
 command.CommandText = " SELECT SUM (SaleTotalValue) FROM SALES where SALES.SaleDate BETWEEN '" + textBoxDate1.Text + "' AND '" + textBoxDate2.Text + "'";
        string cmd = command.CommandText;
        textBoxSalesMonthOutput.Text = Convert.ToString(cmd);
```

Any Ideas of what to do.

Comment: if you run the sql directly what is the output?

Comment: Use parameters instead of SQL injection. This will make your queries more secure and handle conversion issues for you.

Comment: You are not executing your command!!! See [SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [Create and Execute an SQL Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fksx3b4f.aspx)

Comment: Also have a look at [Give me parameterized SQL, or give me death](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/)

Comment: Did any of the answers below help you?

Answer (score 1):

You are not executing your commands.
You can execute them via `ExecuteScalar` as they will only return 1 row and 1 column. Here is an example for your first query :

```
double result = Convert.ToDouble(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

As mentioned in comments by @BabakNaffas, consider using parameters :

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT SUM (PriceSold) FROM SALELINE where SALELINE.SoldBy = @vendor ";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vendor", comboBox10.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Your are not executing the command object. You need to use

```
double result = Convert.ToDouble(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `command.ExecuteScalar` to execute the command and retrieve a single result.